# Array Rand Not Working with MySQL Fetch Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wrote a PHP script that retrieves values from a MySQL Query. I used mysql_fetch_array to add the results to an array. I am trying to select a random value from the array, however array_rand doesn't seem to work. My code is below:

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once 'includes/db_connection.php';
require_once 'includes/contest.php';
require_once 'includes/survey.php';
require_once 'includes/poll.php';
require_once 'includes/clients.php';
require_once 'includes/user.php';
//Select All Entries from Contest and Save as Array
//Select 
mysql_connect(localhost,s2ktest_s2kuser, Bc33iyZYQWgUmguBehPI);
$dbname = 's2ktest_s2k';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$contestid = 20;
$query = "SELECT UserID FROM Contest_Entered WHERE ContestID = $contestid";
//Save Result
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
//Save All Contest Entries in Array
$entries = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

//Output all Rows
//While Each Entry in the Array is a Value
while($entries = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $entries;
echo "</br>";
}
echo array_rand($entries);
//mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does the code generate an error message? Does it always produce the same value? Does it print nothing?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because you don't have any array...
The while is only generating one row at the time.

```
while($entries = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo $entries;
  $arr[] = $entries;
  echo "</br>";
 }
 echo array_rand($arr);
```

Comment: That returns a random number, but I want to output the UserID contained in the array.

Comment: Well, then you only do like this `$arr[$entries['UserID']] = $entries`, if you mean that you want the key equal to the UserID?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array()` retrieves only one row at a time.  First, load the whole result set into an array using the `[]` append syntax, then fetch randomly from that.

```
$all_entries = array();
// Using MYSQL_NUM to retrieve only numeric keys
// by default, mysql_fetch_array() gets both numeric and associative keys
while($entries = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
  // Append all rows onto an array, only a sinlge value so you get a 1D array 
  $all_entries[] = $entries[0];
}
// Then call array_rand() against $all_entries
echo array_rand($all_entries);
```

#### Disclaimer:

Start thinking about migrating away from the old `mysql_*()` functions to a modern API supporting prepared statements.  [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) is excellent and portable between RDBMS, while [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) is a good alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're changing the value of `$entries` from an array to a string when you start the loop. Try echoing `array_rand($entries)` before the loop instead.

However, if you are instead trying to retrieve a random row from a table (rather than a random column from a row, as your code appears to do) use `ORDER BY RAND()` in your query. It's unclear what you're going for.

Good luck!